# Webmethod doesn't hit Angular2, result entire page html

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, webmethod

I have a simple `WebMethod` as below

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static string Redirect()
{
    object a= HttpContext.Current.Session;
    return "yeppieee";
}
```

and calling it as

```
this.http.get(`http://localhost/MyApp/Pages/TestPage.aspx/Redirect`)
        .map(res=>res)    
        .subscribe((res) =>{                
                console.log(res);                                   
                },
                 (err)=>console.log(err),
                 ()=>console.log("Done1111111111")
        );
```

But debugger is not hitting.

On console I can see `Done1111111111`.
In network tab of developer tool I can see status for this request is `200` i.e. `OK`.

Then why `WebMethod` is not getting called?

**Edit**

Just came to know that response is entire html page. I can see that in console.

Comment: set the pst request to this webserice.
use $http.Post

Comment: @SURJEETSINGHBisht I am not posting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to solve this. As it was returning entire page html, I just added content type as json to the request header as below.

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.get(`http://localhost/HelixWebApp/Pages/AngularContainer.aspx/Redirect`, options)
    .map(res=>res.json())    
    .subscribe((res) =>{                
        console.log(res);                                   
        },
        (err)=>console.log(err),
        ()=>console.log("Done")
);
```

Also changed `WebMethod` to accept `GET`

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static string Redirect()
{
    object a= HttpContext.Current.Session;
    return "yeppieee";
}
```